# html image responsive-design

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a problem adjusting the size of an image

I made responsive two images using '%'

one image just has a one circle, the other is one circle + one square6

the circle of images is same image because when first image finished animation,

second image is animated on top of it

when I resize website, second image's circle ratio and first image's circle must adjusted same ratio

please help me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#animate-img2').addClass('hide');
    $('#animate-img').css('display', 'inline');
    $('#animate-img').addClass('fadeIn');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

#animate-img {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

#animate-img2 {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 30%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:absolute;">
  <div style="position:relative;"><img id="animate-img2" class="fadeIn" src="https://s5.postimg.org/6tl50t2r7/image.png"></div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;">
  <div style="position:relative;"><img id="animate-img" src="https://s5.postimg.org/7j3xd6b0j/image.png"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/84e7vL9n/8/

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what exactly you need help with. Please, at least use punctuation.

Comment: @Ilva Linde  sorry. modified it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the question's low readability, I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but could it be that you simply want `$('#animate-img').css('display', 'block');` instead? Example below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#animate-img2').addClass('hide');
    $('#animate-img').css('display', 'block');
    $('#animate-img').addClass('fadeIn');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

#animate-img {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

#animate-img2 {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 30%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:absolute;">
  <div style="position:relative;"><img id="animate-img2" class="fadeIn" src="https://s5.postimg.org/6tl50t2r7/image.png"></div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;">
  <div style="position:relative;"><img id="animate-img" src="https://s5.postimg.org/7j3xd6b0j/image.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: main question is to resize same part of images to same ratio

Answer (score 0):

Please modify this to

```
#animate-img2 {
    z-index:2;
    width:30%;
}
```

this

```
#animate-img2 {
    z-index:2;
    width:28%;
}
```